# Google Cloud Container Registry refuses connection from docker push

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) to push a docker image to my Google Cloud Container Registry. However

```
docker push eu.grc.io/<project-id>/<image>:<tag>
```

only returns

```
The push refers to repository [eu.grc.io/<project-id>/<image>]
Get https://eu.grc.io/v2/: dial tcp xx.xx.xxx.xx:443: connect: connection refused
```

Has anyone encountered this error before or knows how to get it working? I'm seriously out of ideas, there may be something wrong with my network configuration but I'm not familiar enough with that side of Ubuntu to know what I should be looking for. For context, I've set up a kubernetes cluster for hosting jupyterhub following [this guide](https://zero-to-jupyterhub-with-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I can run the image locally, `gcloud info` returns all the correct info and `gcloud auth configure-docker` returns `credential helpers already registered correctly.`

Additional Info:

```
Ubuntu 16.04

gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 214.0.0
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.08.24
gsutil 4.33

docker version
Version:           18.06.1-ce
API version:       1.38
Go version:        go1.10.3
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Typo in your "eu.grc.io".
It is "eu.gcr.io"

Comment: Oh my god this is embarrassing - thank you so much! It's working now!

Comment: It was also my problem LOL

Comment: Hahahahahaha! Awesome!